How to bind specific state machine behaviour with Zenject?
I am Taiwanese, forgive my poor English.
I have a state machine behaviour defined like this :
public class GameStartStateBehaviour : StateMachineBehaviour, IEnterState<SceneType>
{
    public event EventHandler<SceneType> OnEnterState;

    public override void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        OnEnterState?.Invoke(this, SceneType.GamePlayScene);
    }
}

And a SceneLoader class which will listen to OnEnterState event. When enter GameStartState, OnEnterState will be invoked, and told SceneLoader to load a scene. Here is SceneLoader class :
public class SceneLoader : IInitializable, IDisposable
{
    private IEnterState<SceneType> _enterMenuState;
    private IEnterState<SceneType> _enterGameStartState;

    public SceneLoader(
        [Inject(Id = "Menu")]
        IEnterState<SceneType> enterMenuState, 
        [Inject(Id = "GameStart")]
        IEnterState<SceneType> enterGameStartState)
    {
        _enterMenuState = enterMenuState;
        _enterGameStartState = enterGameStartState;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _enterMenuState.OnEnterState += LoadMenuScene;
        _enterGameStartState.OnEnterState += LoadGamePlayScene;
    }
}

And inside GameInstaller:
Container.BindInterfacesAndSelfTo<SceneLoader>().AsSingle().NonLazy();
Container.Bind<IEnterState<SceneType>>().WithId("Menu").To<MenuStateBehaviour>().AsSingle().NonLazy();
Container.Bind<IEnterState<SceneType>>().WithId("GameStart").To<GameStartStateBehaviour>().AsSingle().NonLazy();

Everything seems fine, validation succeeded, and I also checked via the VS debugger that the event was successfully subscribed.
But when enter GameStartState, the event did not invoke.
I suspect that the instance of GameStartStateBehaviour binding in GameInstaller is not the one that used in Animator State Machine, hence the event has no subscribers and doesn't invoke. But I can't figure it out why? Could somebody please tell me what is wrong?
Any help, guides, discussions are very much appreciated.

I believe the issue is that you are not passing the ScriptableObject instance from your project so Zenject is likely creating a new one which is not the one likely added to the Animator
[SerializeField] private GameStartStateBehaviour m_stateMachine;

public override void InstallBindings()
{
    Container.BindInterfacesAndSelfTo<SceneLoader>().FromNew().AsSingle().NonLazy();
    Container.BindInterfacesTo<GameStartStateBehaviour >().WithId("GameStart").FromScriptableObject(m_stateMachine).AsSingle().NonLazy();
}

Then you drag the ScriptableObject of your state machine so you are ensured of which instance is injected and that it will be the same as the one you dragged in the Animator. Then you should be able to use the Inject attribute anywhere you need.

Thanks for your reply. I didn't know that StateMachineBehaviour can be treated as ScriptableObject. Validation succeeded, however it still not working.

Looking from the Unity doc StateMachineBehaviour inherits from ScriptableObject. So I guess you'd need to create an instance of that SO and drag it into wherever it is needed. When you say validation, if you mean the Zenject validation, then it will agree that the code is right but it does not know your intention. In this case, it'd be to share a single instance of a StateMachineBehaviour, but I believe there are multiple instances when you run. You could set debug breakpoint to see what instance is being used during the initialization and call of events.
